# Page orientation in Aspose

Tags: java, aspose, aspose.words

I am using `aspose-words-15.6.0` api for java. I want to change the page orientation to `portrait or landscape` based on the page number.

**Scenario:**

I've a `doc` having 3 pages in it, I want page orientation as follow:

- 1st Page : Portrait.
- 2nd Page : Landscape.
- 3rd Page : Portrait.

**EDIT:**

I have tried with `DocumentBuilder`, there is a way to achieve this but I am missing something, please refer the screenshot I've attached with this question.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no concept of Page in MS Word documents. Pages are created by Microsoft Word on the fly and unfortunately there is no straight forward way that you can use to set orientation per Page. However, you can specify orientation settings for a whole Section using **Section.PageSetup.Orientation** property and a Section may contain more than just one Page.

Alternatively, you may be able create a separate Section for each page in word document using Aspose.Words and then specify page orientation for each Section corresponding to a particular page. Please report this requirement in [Aspose.Words forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx), we will then develop code for this requirement and provide you more information.

**EDIT:**

If you want to build document from scratch, please use the following code:

```
Document doc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

builder.writeln("Content on first page");
builder.getPageSetup().setOrientation(Orientation.PORTRAIT);
builder.insertBreak(BreakType.SECTION_BREAK_NEW_PAGE);

builder.writeln("Content on second page");
builder.getPageSetup().setOrientation(Orientation.LANDSCAPE);
builder.insertBreak(BreakType.SECTION_BREAK_NEW_PAGE);

builder.writeln("Content on third page");
builder.getPageSetup().setOrientation(Orientation.PORTRAIT);

doc.save(getMyDir() + "15.10.0.docx");
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Could you please look into the DocumentBuilder approach.

Comment: Please check I have added code in [my previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33887426/4952051). Hope, this helps. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments, let me test this on my system. I will get back to you soon.

Comment: The code above generates a document with three pages such that the first page is portrait, second is landscape and third page has again portrait orientation. Could you please elaborate your inquiry further what problems  are you facing with this code on your end?  I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, In aspose we can change the orientation only if we are inserting new pages. There is not function to change orientation of existing pages based on the page number or section. Right?

Comment: Your understanding is correct but this is how MS Word also works. As mentioned in [my first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33887426/4952051), there is no straight forward way that you can use to set orientation per Page of an existing document. However, you can specify orientation settings for a whole Section using Section.PageSetup.Orientation property. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.